# VBA best way to code repeated conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I have six locations a, b, c, d, e, f in my pivot slicer and I five have box shapes based which are grey in color. Based on the selection in the slicer the box color will change to green. When all locations are selected all the box will become green.
I have achieved this through if condition in VBA. But I am confused on how to satisfy condition where user selects only three or two locations. What is the best way to code to satisfy this condition

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    If Target.Name = "PivotTable4" Then
        If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Site_work_being_carried_out").SlicerItems("a").Selected = True Then
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 6").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = vbGreen
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 15").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 11").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 12").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 7").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 9").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
        ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Site_work_being_carried_out").SlicerItems("b").Selected = True Then
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 15").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = vbGreen
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 6").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 11").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 12").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 7").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 9").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
        ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Site_work_being_carried_out").SlicerItems("c").Selected = True Then
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 11").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = vbGreen
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 15").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 6").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 12").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 7").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 9").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
        ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Site_work_being_carried_out").SlicerItems("d").Selected = True Then
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 12").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = vbGreen
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 11").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 15").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 6").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 7").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 9").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
        ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Site_work_being_carried_out").SlicerItems("e").Selected = True Then
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 7").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = vbGreen
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 12").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 11").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 15").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 6").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 9").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
        ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Site_work_being_carried_out").SlicerItems("f").Selected = True Then
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 9").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = vbGreen
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 7").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 12").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 11").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 15").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform: Shape 6").Fill.ForeColor
                .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Start by posting the code you have and please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are  talking about 5 locations and 5 shapes, but there are 6 in the code - make it clear please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictionary to store shape names and corresponding slicer names, and set shapes color depending on slicers selected state:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Dim sShape
    If Target.Name = "PivotTable4" Then
        ' instantiate dictionary
        With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            ' fill the dict with shape names as keys and corresponding slicer names as values
            .Item("Freeform: Shape 6") = "a"
            .Item("Freeform: Shape 15") = "b"
            .Item("Freeform: Shape 11") = "c"
            .Item("Freeform: Shape 12") = "d"
            .Item("Freeform: Shape 7") = "e"
            .Item("Freeform: Shape 9") = "f"
            ' set forecolor for each shape depending on corresponding slicer actual selected state
            For Each sShape In .Keys
                Target.Parent.Shapes(sShape).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = IIf( _
                    Target.Parent.Parent.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Site_work_being_carried_out").SlicerItems(.Item(sShape)).Selected, _
                    vbGreen, _
                    RGB(205, 192, 176) _
                )
            Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Or even you can use nested arrays:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Dim aShape
    If Target.Name = "PivotTable4" Then
        ' loop through shapes using array populated by nested arrays with shape/slicer name pairs
        For Each aShape In Array( _
            Array("Freeform: Shape 6", "a"), _
            Array("Freeform: Shape 15", "b"), _
            Array("Freeform: Shape 11", "c"), _
            Array("Freeform: Shape 12", "d"), _
            Array("Freeform: Shape 7", "e"), _
            Array("Freeform: Shape 9", "f") _
        )
            ' set forecolor for the shape depending on the slicer actual selected state
            Target.Parent.Shapes(aShape(0)).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = IIf( _
                Target.Parent.Parent.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Site_work_being_carried_out").SlicerItems(aShape(1)).Selected, _
                vbGreen, _
                RGB(205, 192, 176) _
            )
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Didn't tested since I had no such data structure, If I right understand what  you intended, that should work.

Note that it is not a best way to rely on `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet` global properties. I've changed `ActiveWorkbook` with `Target.Parent.Parent`, and `ActiveSheet` with `Target.Parent`.

Comment: I get an error object doesn't support this property in this line "If .Item(sShape) Then"

Comment: @Danny I see, it's my fault, I didn't tested the code, take a look at fixed version for dictionary and alternative for nested arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @omegastripes, .item is not allowed in if so added a var d and it worked

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Dim sShape
    Dim d
    If Target.Name = "PivotTable4" Then
        ' instantiate dictionary
        Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        With d
            ' fill the dict with shape names as keys and corresponding slicer names as values
            .Item("Freeform: Shape 6") = "a"
            .Item("Freeform: Shape 15") = "b"
            .Item("Freeform: Shape 11") = "c"
            .Item("Freeform: Shape 12") = "d"
            .Item("Freeform: Shape 7") = "e"
            .Item("Freeform: Shape 9") = "f"
            ' replace each slicer name with it's actual selected state
            For Each sShape In .Keys
                d.Item(sShape) = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Site_work_being_carried_out").SlicerItems(.Item(sShape)).Selected
            Next
            ' set forecolor for each shape individually
            For Each sShape In .Keys
                With ActiveSheet.Shapes(sShape).Fill.ForeColor
                    If d.Item(sShape) Then
                        .RGB = vbGreen
                    Else
                        .RGB = RGB(205, 192, 176)
                    End If
                End With
            Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: All those `d.Item` before the `For Each` block should be replaced with just `.Item`, otherwise there is no reason to use `With d` at all, since you are not taking advantage of it